# C# Optional Parameters or Method Overload?

Tags: c#, coding-style, overloading, optional-parameters

Since C# added optional parameters is it considered a better practice to use optional parameters or method overloads or is there a particular case where you would want to use one over the other. i.e a function w/ lots of parameters would be better suited w/ optional parameters?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Optional parameters are nice, but should be used when it makes sense. Optional parameters often muddy the intent of the method -- If there is another alternative I would lean towards the alternative.

Part of the need for optional parameters and named parameters is because COM allowed optional and name parameters:

**MSDN**

> Some APIs, most notably COM interfaces
>   such as the Office automation APIs,
>   are written specifically with named
>   and optional parameters in mind. Up
>   until now it has been very painful to
>   call into these APIs from C#, with
>   sometimes as many as thirty arguments
>   having to be explicitly passed, most
>   of which have reasonable default
>   values and could be omitted.

SomeNewKid from forums.asp.net puts succinctly:

http://forums.asp.net/t/386604.aspx/1

> ...overloaded methods are generally
>   preferable to optional parameters.
>   Why? To keep each of your methods
>   clear in purpose. That is, each method
>   should do one thing well. As soon as
>   you introduce optional parameters, you
>   are diluting the cleanliness of that
>   method, and introducing branching
>   logic that is probably best kept out
>   of a method. This clarity of purpose
>   becomes even more important when you
>   start using inheritance. If you
>   override a method that has one or more
>   optional parameters, they become
>   harder to work with. So, I'd suggest
>   that for anything other than quick and
>   dirty classes, you use overloading in
>   preference to optional parameters.

Keep in mind that optional parameters are a syntactical sugar:

**Reflector C#:**

```
public class Class1
{
    // Methods
    public Class1()
    {
        this.Method1("3", "23");
    }

    public void Method1(string one, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("23")] string two)
    {
    }
}
```

**IL:**

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Class1
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldarg.0 
        L_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        L_0006: nop 
        L_0007: nop 
        L_0008: ldarg.0 
        L_0009: ldstr "3"
        L_000e: ldstr "23"
        L_0013: call instance void WebApplication1.Class1::Method1(string, string)
        L_0018: nop 
        L_0019: nop 
        L_001a: ret 
    }

    .method public hidebysig instance void Method1(string one, [opt] string two) cil managed
    {
        .param [2] = string('23')
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: nop 
        L_0001: ret 
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know, in my experience 16 overloads is what _really_ muddies the water. 4 optional parameters are much less muddy in comparison. An extreme example, of course, but I do not see how your average set of overloads does anything like the idealistic quote from SomeNewKid; you just usually get 2ⁿ overloads for n = how many optional parameters there are. If you find yourself doing this, please just use optional parameters instead.

Comment: One advantage of overloads is that it's easier to find reference you're actually looking for when using IDE tools such as ReSharper or what is built-in to Visual Studio.   If I have optional parameters, and I'm looking for the reference that calls with 2 parameters vs. 3 parameters, it's not as easy to do.

Comment: VB.Net always supported optional parameters and they are used extensively on many big VB projects.  They are particularly handy when you want to extend the parameter list of a function without revisiting every existing call to it.   The lack of optional parameters presented serious issues in the migration of large-scale VB projects to C#.  I suspect this was a significant motivation for adding them to C#.

Answer (score 13):

Code Analysis in Visual Studio and FxCop recommends you do not use optional arguments in public APIs (rule [CA1026: Default parameters should not be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182135.aspx)). The reason given is that not all .NET languages support them.

I think a better reason to avoid them though, is that they can introduce either runtime or compile-time problems if you add more overloads in a version 2.0 of your API. [Phil Haack explains here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/08/10/versioning-issues-with-optional-arguments.aspx).

I'm going to adopt Phil's conclusion: Optional parameters were designed to support COM interop; if you're not using COM, leave them alone.

Comment: These are excellent points *if* you're building a public API. The 'rules' are obviously quite different for internal methods, though some people do elect to follow API design guidelines even for internal methods. Which is fine also.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure there's a canonical answer for this - it's subjective and case-by-case. However, in my opinion optional parameters create more explicit APIs and therefore, I generally prefer them over method overloads.

Specifically, when working with Intellisense I much prefer to see this:

[image: optional params with defaults]

Over this:

[image: overload 1]

[image: overload 2]

[image: overload 3]

Where I may have to guess (or look up documentation) for what the value of param1 and param2 will be if I don't specify.

Comment: @hemp using optional parameters creates ambiguity. You end up with one method that does many things. The method will have different behavior based on it's input. A method should do one thing and one thing only.

Comment: @Chuck I disagree wholeheartedly, which is why I started by saying the question is subjective in nature. Further, the argument for "a method should do one thing and one thing only" is a tired one and oft abused. Worse, the *most common implementation* pattern I see for overloaded methods is to have one overload call the other, passing in a default value.

Comment: @hemp using an overloaded method to set a default, is encapsulating and isolates the difference from the implementation. There is no ambiguity in this approach.

Comment: @Chuck It is not possible to resolve the 'ambiguity' issue because that is purely subjective. However, using an overloaded method to set a default violates your position against having branching logic within a method because the ultimate callee in that scenario behaves differently based on the value passed in.

Comment: While I agree that the "one thing only" method is a thing of computer science courses, the extraction of multiple overloaded method does make sense.  Each overload is/should be treated as a use case that has distinct parameter validation and possibly even logic.  Like mentioned, it is largely suggestive, but I find having succinct use cases for optional parameters as a kludge and means to provide a nest for the development of some interesting bugs.  It is much easier to test a series of overloads than to come up with all the possible permutations of optional parameters in a lot of cases.

Comment: @joseph: Thank you for your thoughtful comments. I certainly agree that creating methods with many permutations of optional parameters is a problem, but I think that goes equally for permutations of overloaded methods. e.g. If you have 12 methods with the same name, how can that name possibly describe adequately the behavior of all 12 methods? It's a code smell and a testing challenge either way (whether achieved via overloads or optional parameters.)

Comment: If there are more than a few parameters, I would recommend making a class that contains the parameters, and perhap.s a constructor for the class containing the default parameters

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson [XmlWriterSettings Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an example of the approach that you recommend. In the code example for that class, the factory method `XmlWriter.Create` takes an `XmlWriterSettings` argument to create an `XmlWriter`.

Comment: Passing a parameter object does nothing to help reduce either the code smell or complexity. It just shrinks the parameter list for the method. These arguments that one is intrinsically better than the other come from comp sci courses as facts which must be accepted, but they have little actual merit.

If you give me one function that takes an object containing 12 fields and ask me to write tests for that function, it is mathematically no different than me writing tests for an otherwise identical function which takes those same 12 values as optional parameters with defaults.

Comment: I would say that regardless of whether you have 12 arguments or 12 overloads or a parameter object with 12 properties, it's a code smell since you almost certainly have a method that's doing many things.

Answer (score 4):

Optional parameters are meant to facilitate COM object interactions as COM objects use lots of optional parameters. So if you're doing P/Invoke or COM object stuff, prefer optional parameters. Otherwise, method overloading is the proper way to go as it saves a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than overloading or named optional parameters, I've grown to like object initializers very much. All you need in the class is a parameterless constructor, and public properties for anything you want to set on initialization.

Assuming class Bar has public string properties "Name" and "Pet", you can construct a new object like this.

```
var foo = new Bar { Name = "Fred", Pet = "Dino" };
```

The advantage is that you don't need a separate overload for each combination of values that you want to initialize.

Comment: This is a nice feature, but it requires your objects to be mutable. I tend to prefer immutable types wherever possible.

Comment: Immutable and mutable both have their place, and in C#, enforcing immutability can require more work than readonly properties and private setters. Any "change" requires constructing a new object and returning it in place of the original. So, as in most things, "it depends."

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters require a default value (I only assume), and thus in some cases it might be difficult to supply one. Why? Well some classes need runtime information to get initialized which may not be available to the compiler.

When it comes to primitive types, the answer may have to do with if a default value can be assumed, or if the absence of a parameter might signify different behavior by the method.

Comment: If a default value cannot be provided then using optional parameters would be nonsensical. In that case, make it a required parameter. If a default value can be determined only at run-time, then a null or special-case default could suffice as a trigger to look up the correct value. But I'd argue that's indicative of a code smell and likely a better design is needed, perhaps using a class factory or some other appropriate pattern.